# Mysql wont start on Mac OSX?

Tags: mysql, permissions, osx-snow-leopard, startup

I am a totally newbie on both Mac and Mysql (almost)!

I am having problems to get the mysql to start.

System is Mac osX 10.6.5
Proc is Intel Core 2 Duo (64Bit)
Mysql is 5.5.8 for osx 10.6 -> X86_64

It wont start if I use the applet that is installed in systemsettings.
It wont startup when I boot my computer, even if the checkbox is ticked.
The system gets me an error on boot in "startUpItems/Mysqlcom/" and telling me that there is a permission problem?

Any ideas how I should troubleshoot this?

Best regards, Joakim

Comment: what permission problem ? please post the exact error you get .

Comment: yes, by moving this question to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.5 has an issue with permissions on Snow Leopard.  Try this:

```
chown -R root:wheel /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
```

and edit /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server (lines 46-57):

```
basedir=/usr/local/mysql datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
```

If that doesn't work, you might want to install 5.1.x as that worked fine on Snow Leopard.

Comment: I keep getting this happen still on lion & mysql 5.5.24